# Spring Security with JWT for REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, rest

I have this class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SALT = "fd&lkj§isfs23#$1*(_)nof";

    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
    private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    private final UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;


    public ApiWebSecurityConfig(JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler, JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
            UserSecurityService userSecurityService) {
        this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
        this.userSecurityService = userSecurityService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userSecurityService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12, new SecureRandom(SALT.getBytes()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
                // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
                .csrf().disable()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()

                // don't create session
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                // Un-secure H2 Database
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/users").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(userDetailsService(), jwtTokenUtil, tokenHeader);
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // disable page caching
        httpSecurity
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .sameOrigin()  // required to set for H2 else H2 Console will be blank.
                .cacheControl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {

        // AuthenticationTokenFilter will ignore the below paths
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        "/api/v1/auth"
                )
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        "/api/v1/users"
                )
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/api/v1/countries"
                );

    }

}
```

and

```
@Provider
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    private String tokenHeader;

    public JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
            JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
            String tokenHeader) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
        this.tokenHeader = tokenHeader;
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new AntPathMatcher().match("/api/v1/users",
                request.getServletPath());
    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException,
            IOException {

        log.info("processing authentication for '{}'", request.getRequestURL());
        log.info("tokenHeader '{}'", tokenHeader);

        final String requestHeader = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);

        log.info("requestHeader '{}'", requestHeader);

        String username = null;
        String authToken = null;

        if (requestHeader != null && requestHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            authToken = requestHeader.substring(7);

            log.info("authToken '{}'", authToken);

            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.info("an error occured during getting username from token", e);
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.info("the token is expired and not valid anymore", e);
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("couldn't find bearer string, will ignore the header");
        }

        log.info("checking authentication for user '{}'", username);

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            logger.info("security context was null, so authorizating user");

            // It is not compelling necessary to load the use details from the database. You could also store the information
            // in the token and read it from it. It's up to you ;)
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            // For simple validation it is completely sufficient to just check the token integrity. You don't have to call
            // the database compellingly. Again it's up to you ;)
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                log.info("authorizated user '{}', setting security context", username);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

and

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class AuthenticationRestController {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger   (AuthenticationRestController.class);

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    @PostMapping(path = "/api/v1/auth", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<JwtAuthenticationResponse>
    createAuthenticationToken(  @RequestBody JwtAuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationException {

        LOG.info("authenticating {} " , authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        authenticate(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        // Reload password post-security so we can generate the token
        final User userDetails = (User) userSecurityService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

        if (!userDetails.isEnabled()) {
            throw new UserDisabledException();
        }

        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("UserDetails userDetails [ " + authenticationRequest.getUsername() + " ]");
        }


        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        // Return the token
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(token));
    }


    @GetMapping(path = "${jwt.route.authentication.refresh}", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> refreshAndGetAuthenticationToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authToken = request.getHeader(tokenHeader);
        final String token = authToken.substring(7);
        String username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(token);
        JwtUser user = (JwtUser) userSecurityService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if (jwtTokenUtil.canTokenBeRefreshed(token, user.getLastPasswordResetDate())) {
            String refreshedToken = jwtTokenUtil.refreshToken(token);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(refreshedToken));
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(null);
        }
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({AuthenticationException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleAuthenticationException(AuthenticationException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(e.getMessage());
    }

    /**
     * Authenticates the user. If something is wrong, an {@link AuthenticationException} will be thrown
     */
    private void authenticate(String username, String password) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(username);
        Objects.requireNonNull(password);


        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
        } catch (DisabledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AuthenticationException("User is disabled!", e);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Bad credentials!", e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/styles")
@Slf4j
public class StyleResourceController  {

    
    @PutMapping(path = "/{styleCode}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void setAlerts(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authHeader, @PathVariable String styleCode)

            throws DataAccessException {

        System.out.println("add style {} ");

        final User user = authUserOnPath(authHeader);

        System.out.println("user {} " + user);

            protected User authUserOnPath(String authHeader) {

        String authToken = authHeader.substring(7);

        String username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
        User user = userService.findByUserName(username);

        if (user == null)
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "UserNotFound");

        return user;

    }


    }

}
```

and

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {

    //static final String CLAIM_KEY_USERNAME = "sub";
    //static final String CLAIM_KEY_CREATED = "iat";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3301605591108950415L;
    // @SuppressFBWarnings(value = "SE_BAD_FIELD", justification = "It's okay here")
    private Clock clock = DefaultClock.INSTANCE;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.expiration}")
    private Long expiration;

    public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date getIssuedAtDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getIssuedAt);
    }

    public Date getExpirationDateFromToken(String token) {
        return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T getClaimFromToken(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(secret)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        final Date expiration = getExpirationDateFromToken(token);
        return expiration.before(clock.now());
    }

    private Boolean isCreatedBeforeLastPasswordReset(Date created, Date lastPasswordReset) {
        return (lastPasswordReset != null && created.before(lastPasswordReset));
    }

    private Boolean ignoreTokenExpiration(String token) {
        // here you specify tokens, for that the expiration is ignored
        return false;
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return doGenerateToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String doGenerateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        final Date createdDate = clock.now();
        final Date expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(createdDate);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuedAt(createdDate)
                .setExpiration(expirationDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
                .compact();
    }

    public Boolean canTokenBeRefreshed(String token, Date lastPasswordReset) {
        final Date created = getIssuedAtDateFromToken(token);
        return !isCreatedBeforeLastPasswordReset(created, lastPasswordReset)
                && (!isTokenExpired(token) || ignoreTokenExpiration(token));
    }

    public String refreshToken(String token) {
        final Date createdDate = clock.now();
        final Date expirationDate = calculateExpirationDate(createdDate);

        final Claims claims = getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
        claims.setIssuedAt(createdDate);
        claims.setExpiration(expirationDate);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
                .compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        JwtUser user = (JwtUser) userDetails;
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        final Date created = getIssuedAtDateFromToken(token);
        return (
                username.equals(user.getUsername())
                        && !isTokenExpired(token)
                        && !isCreatedBeforeLastPasswordReset(created, user.getLastPasswordResetDate())
        );
    }

    private Date calculateExpirationDate(Date createdDate) {
        return new Date(createdDate.getTime() + expiration * 1000);
    }
}
```

but when I get the user from the token is null:

```
17:19:22.017 [http-nio-1133-exec-8] INFO  c.d.c.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter - tokenHeader 'Authorization'
17:19:22.017 [http-nio-1133-exec-8] INFO  c.d.c.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter - requestHeader 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2OTE3NjcxMzYsImlhdCI6MTYzMTI4NzEzNn0.C9s3dbjWNVyGdV5k0LXsNhMGMvPzboTx1J6sGEbfXVOP1CzCLeZFgVPQ4o8jgugvgURF3BcnsWAk7ygd7RCvdg'
17:19:22.017 [http-nio-1133-exec-8] INFO  c.d.c.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter - authToken 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2OTE3NjcxMzYsImlhdCI6MTYzMTI4NzEzNn0.C9s3dbjWNVyGdV5k0LXsNhMGMvPzboTx1J6sGEbfXVOP1CzCLeZFgVPQ4o8jgugvgURF3BcnsWAk7ygd7RCvdg'
17:19:22.018 [http-nio-1133-exec-8] INFO  c.d.c.JwtAuthorizationTokenFilter - checking authentication for user 'null'
```

Comment: Your token does not contain a username, so focus your effort to the creation part.

Comment: Couldn't find any user related data in your token. Paste your JWT token [here](https://jwt.io/). You need to add user related data inside your token when you crates them.

Comment: As indicated by sam and ray, your token does not contain any user information (if you copy and paste the token in jet.io, for instance, it will provide no `sub` value in the payload). The create `createAuthenticationToken` method looks fine as well as `generateToken`. Please, try debugging your ÙserDetails` instance before this line: `final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);`. Also, be sure that your `UserDetails` correctly implements the `getUsername` method, sometimes we derived it from the database and we didn't implement it correctly. Try debugging the method ...

Comment: `doGenerateToken` as well, and see the value of the `subject` variable. I hope I helps.

Comment: Sorry, I want to say [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), not jet.io. My computer translator.

Comment: @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;  in AuthenticationRestController,  you are bringing the header part only.. trying using jwt.payload instead jwt.header of  to get Subject Details

Comment: @Nunyet what is the `UserSecurityService`? Is it your own implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enter code here`@Component
public class JwtUtil {

```
 @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

 @Value("${jwt.expiration}") 
 private Long expiration;
 
 Date now =new Date();
 Date ExpirationDate =new Date(now.getTime()+ expiration*1000);

public User getUser(final String token) {
    Claims body = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(secret)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();

    User u = new User();
    u.setUsername(body.getSubject());
    u.setUserId(Integer.parseInt((String) body.get("userId")));
    Set<Role> roles =new HashSet<>(); 
    roles.add(Role.CONSUMER);
    roles.add(Role.SELLER);
    u.setRoles(roles);
    return u;
}

public String generateToken(String username) {
       User u = new User();
      Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(username);
        claims.put("userId", u.getUserId());
        Set<Role> roles =new HashSet<>(); 
        roles.add(Role.CONSUMER);
        roles.add(Role.SELLER);
        claims.put("role",roles );

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration( ExpirationDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, secret)
                .compact();
    
}

public boolean validateToken(final String token) {
    return getClaims(secret,token)
            .getExpiration()
            .after(new Date (System.currentTimeMillis()));
}

public Claims getClaims(String secret ,String token) {
    return Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(secret)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Double check your jwt token. I think it miss sub attribute( subject or username here).

I also highly recommend you write the few unit test for few class such as JwtTokenUtil to make sure your code working as expected. You can use spring-test to do it easily.

It help you discover the bug easier and sooner.

Here is few test which i used to test the commands "jwt generate" and "jwt parse"

```
@Test
  public void testInvalidKey() {
    String result = execute("jwt generate ");
    Assertions.assertEquals(JsonWebToken.ERR_LOAD_PRIVATE_KEY, result);
  }

  @Test
  public void testInvalidExpiredDate() {
    String result = execute(
        "jwt generate -exp \"12-12-2020\"");
    Assertions.assertEquals(JsonWebToken.ERR_INVALID_EXPIRED_DATE, result);
  }

  @Test
  public void testGenerateOk() {
    String result = execute(
        "jwt generate");
    Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
    Assertions.assertTrue(result.length() > 100);
  }

  @Test
  public void testParseToken() {
    String result = execute(
        "jwt generate -sub designer");
    Assertions.assertNotNull(result);
    String parse = execute("jwt parse -token " + result);    
    Assertions.assertTrue(parse.contains("sub:designer"));
  }
```

And here is few other test which i used to check the controller and filter.

```
@Test
  public void testInValidToken() throws Exception{
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(reqObj);
      mockMvc.perform(postWithTokenAndData(getUrlProvider(), map)
          .header(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Bearer %s", INVALID_JWT))
          .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is4xxClientError());
  }
  
  @Test
  public void testExpired() throws Exception{
    Date exp = Date.from(Instant.now().minusSeconds(3600));
      Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(reqObj);
      mockMvc.perform(postWithTokenAndData(getUrlProvider(), map)
          .header(HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Bearer %s", JwtHelperTest.getJwtToken(exp,
              "designer")))
          .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
          .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is4xxClientError());
  }
```